# Cut-off functions and compactly supported Fourier transforms.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose you have a cut-off function $\varphi(x)$ such that $\widehat{\varphi}(\xi) \in C_0^\infty$ is even, real valued and non-negative with compact support on a symmetric interval $[-a,a]$ for $a>0$.  Is it possible to define another cut-off function $\tilde{\varphi} = \tilde{\varphi}(2^\delta x)$, with $\delta >0$ such that $\tilde{\varphi}\varphi \approx \varphi^2$ for appropriately chosen $\delta$?

Comment: What means this $\approx$?

Comment: Approximately. Though it would be nice to have equality.